# Cannot remove products in category

Tags: magento2, error, category-products, magento2.2.3

I got this error when I tried to remove a **product** from **category** page

> Something went wrong while saving the category

Currently, I'm working with **Magento 2.2.3**.

Can anyone please explain about this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are getting error in your log files

1. var/log/exception.log
2. var/log/system.log

If these files are not there or empty, make sure you enable errors from admin:

1. Log into your Magento Admin Backend.
2. Go to System ->> Configuration.
3. Click on "Developer" in the left side menu section.
4. Open the "Log Settings" section.
5. Change the "Enabled" to "Yes"
6. Click "Save Config"
7. Flush Cache